# Rendering of UK Girobank tear-off slips

Tags: pdf, icons, itext, ocr

I need to render the Girobank tear-off slips that are commonly found on UK invoices for utility bills (electricity/gas/water)

I'm using iText to create PDF so placement/sizing won't be a problem but I'm not sure which font to use and exact placement requirements of the number that will be read by OCR systems at banks/post offices.  I'm also having difficulty finding the relevant icons (Girobank, Transcash, bank giro credit) that need to be placed on the invoice.

Does anyone have any experience and/or know of any resources that can help me with this?

Comment: You could create your own font containing those icons and add that to the PDF. Or search a font that has those icons. (Don't really know if that's your problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some research has led me to the aptly named OCR-B font which appears to be the correct one for the identification line at the bottom of the slip.  (Incidentally OCR-A is the font used on books for ISBN numbers).

Useful links

[OCR-B font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCR-B)

[OCR-A/OCR-B free download](http://ansuz.sooke.bc.ca/page/fonts#ocrb)